# Birthday Problem: Months and Dates should be taken into consideration

Tags: probability

In a family of four, what is the probability that no two people have the same birthdays in the same month.(Assuming that all the months have equal probability)

Firstly I understood the question to be similar to the one that asks for the probability of no two people having the sam birthdate. 
So I tried that P(of no two people sharing the same Bday in same month)= 1-P( two people have the same Bday)

1-4C2/30 (Assuming that every month has 30 days. =1-0.2 =0.8.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you simply asking what is the probability that no two family members share a birthday?  Or that no two family members share a birthmonth?  If the former, why do you specify months?

Comment: Hard to follow.  what does the $30$ have to do with anything?  Order them (by age, say).  The probability that the first two have different birthmonths is $\frac {11}{12}$.  The probability that the third has yet a different birthmonth is then $\frac {10}{12}, and $\frac 9{12}$ for the fourth.  Thus....

Answer (score 1):

As Xander Henderson said, if the question is just 'what is the probability that two people have the same birthday' then individual months is not relevant- though the year, whether a leap year or not, can.

There are 365 days in a non-leap year.  Person "A" has *some* birthday.  In order that person "B" has the same birthday, his birthday must be that 1 day out of 365.  The probability of that is 1/365.

There are 365 days in a leap year.  Person "A" has *some* birthday.  In order that person "B" has the same birthday, his birthday must be that 1 day out of 366.  The probability of that is 1/366.

To get the "overall" probability, use the fact that 1/4 of all years are leap years, 3/4 are not*.  So the probability two people share the same birthday is (3/4)(1/365)+ (1/4)(1/366).

- Strictly speaking, this is not exactly true.  In the Gregorian calendar, Any year divisible by 100 but not divisible by 400, is NOT a leap year.  1800 and 1900, though divisible by 4 were not leap years because they are divisible by 100.  The year 2000 **was** a leap year. It is divisible by 100 but also by 400.